# Links do docker-compose - Laravel + Redis

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis

Estou criando uma ambiente de desenvolvimento para um projeto laravel 5.0 baseado em docker.

Gerei um arquivo `docker-compose.yml` pelo http://phpdocker.io e fiz algumas modificações, ele está dessa forma:

```
###############################################################################
#                          Generated on phpdocker.io                          #
###############################################################################
version: "3.1"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: rdias-app-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - redis

  php-fpm:
    build: phpdocker/php-fpm
    container_name: rdias-app-php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
    links:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: rdias-app-redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass Redis2019!
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/data
```

A aplicação está funcionando corretamente mas ela não conecta de forma nenhuma no redis.

A maquina host consegue conectar sem problemas.

Eu não sei se fiz o link da forma correta. Não estou acostumado com docker.

Comment: No links, passa o nome do container, ex: `redis:rdias-app-redis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema de uma forma simples. Apenas passando como o host do redis, a string `redis` referente ao nome do serviço no docker.